# Getting gpg key error while installing RVM

Tags: rvm

While installing rvm I get the following error. What can I do?

```
jsr@jsr-Vostro-1550:~$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0     83      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    83
100 22817  100 22817    0     0   4686      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 11278
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.10.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.10/1.26.10.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Monday 02 February 2015 09:39:00 PM IST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).

GPG signature verification failed for '/home/jsr/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.10.tgz' - 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.10/1.26.10.tar.gz.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:

    gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

or if it fails:

    command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -

the key can be compared with:

    https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
    https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

[image: gpg error]

Comment: If any of the posts below solved your problem you can accept that post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, please execute the following:

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys BF04FF17
```